# How delete a html table row using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to delete a row when i click the glyphicon-trash. I tried many ways but still cant get row index properly.

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="table_GemList">
<thead>
  <col style="width: 25%">
  <col style="width: 25%">
  <col style="width: 25%">
  <col style="width: 25%">
</thead>
<tbody id="GemListBody">
<tr>
  <td>Oval</td>
  <td>Red</td>
  <td>2.23</td>
  <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Box</td>
  <td>Pink</td>
  <td>2.23</td>
  <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

---------- My code

```
 $(document).on("click", ".glyphicon-trash", function () {

        var d = $(this).parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
        document.getElementById("table_GemList").deleteRow(d);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update

```
var d = $(this).parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
document.getElementById("table_GemList").deleteRow(d);
```

to

```
$(this).closest("tr").remove();
```

For reference on `closest()` - https://api.jquery.com/closest/

For reference on `remove()` - https://api.jquery.com/remove/

Answer (score 3):

`$(this)` returns a jQuery object. You can't directly read the properties of the collection's items that way. In fact you shouldn't wrap the element with the jQuery constructor as you don't want to use the jQuery APIs.

```
var d = this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
```

Since you are using jQuery, you can simply use the `closest` and `remove` methods.

```
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe this helps....**

```
 $(document).on("click", ".glyphicon-trash", function ()
 {
     $(this).closest("tr").remove(); // remove row
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

This should works.

```
$(document).on("click", ".glyphicon-trash", function () {
  $(this).parents('tr:first').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply delete the parent  in which trash icons is there by below jquery code

```
 $(document).on("click", ".glyphicon-trash", function (){
 $(this).parent().parent().remove(); // remove row
```

});